# merge two yaml files so list has extra values if necessary

Tags: yaml, yq

In my shell script, there is a part where a command uses a yaml file, and I want this yaml file to be slightly different depending on the value of a variable that is accessible within the shell script.

The yaml file is as follows:

```
name: John
friends:
  - friendName: Bob
    family:
       extended:
          cousins:
             - Sarah
             - Jane
             - Tom
age: 12
```

However, depending on the value of the aforementioned variable, I might also want the yaml file to be as follows (i.e. adding more values to the `cousins` list):

```
name: John
friends:
  - friendName: Bob
    family:
       extended:
          cousins:
             - Sarah
             - Jane
             - Tom
             - Arthur
             - Michael
             - Frank
age: 12
```

I understand that yaml files do not support conditional statements, and ideally I'd like to not repeat content in the yaml file. Is there a way to merge two yaml files such that if the same list is present in both files, they are combined (and thus achieves my desired goal of adding more values to the `cousins` list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Multiply](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/multiply-merge) can do it with the variant `*+`, which concatenates sequences:

```
yq eval-all 'select(fileIndex == 0) *+ select(fileIndex == 1)' file1.yaml file2.yaml
```

given the inputs:

```yaml
# file1.yaml
---
- one
- two
- three
...
# file2.yaml
---
- three
- four
- five
```

You will get

```yaml
- one
- two
- three
- three
- four
- five
```

Note how *concatenate* means that any value present in both lists gets duplicated. There is nothing you can do about it, that's just how lists work. If you don't want to duplicate items, you have to use sets instead, which have that semantic. In YAML, you define sets by giving mappings with no values:

```yaml
# file1.yaml
---
? one
? two
? three
...
# file2.yaml
---
? three
? four
? five
```

Applying the same operation on those will give you

```yaml
one:
two:
three:
four:
five:
```

(yeah, `yq` isn't able to keep the `?` syntax here which is nicer for pure sets, but the semantics are the same)

But what if the final YAML has to contain lists? Well, we need sets initially to do the merging, but we can transform those into sequences afterwards, e.g. these inputs:

```yaml
# file1.yaml
---
some:
  list:
    ? one
    ? two
    ? three
...
# file2.yaml
---
some:
  list:
    ? three
    ? four
    ? five
```

processed with this command:

```
yq eval-all 'select(fileIndex == 0) *+ select(fileIndex == 1) | .some.list |= keys' file1.yaml file2.yaml
```

will give you:

```yaml
some:
  list:
    - one
    - two
    - three
    - four
    - five
```

But since we can modify the data on the fly, we can *also* make it so that we can input sequences, which will be converted to sets, combined, and then re-written as sequences. With this input

```yaml
# file1.yaml
---
some:
  list:
    - one
    - two
    - three
...
# file2.yaml
---
some:
  list:
    - three
    - four
    - five
```

and this command

```
yq eval-all '
  (select(fileIndex == 0) | .some.list |= ((.[] | {.: ""}) as $item
    ireduce ({}; . * $item)))
*+
  (select(fileIndex == 1) | .some.list |= ((.[] | {.: ""}) as $item
    ireduce ({}; . * $item)))
| .some.list |= keys' file1.yaml file2.yaml
```

you get

```yaml
some:
  list:
    - one
    - two
    - three
    - four
    - five
```

Now the question is: Can you justify this level of complexity for your task?